# Rotating quotes Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help implementing a rotating quote jquery plugin.

Here is the Jquery Code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.quovolver = function(speed, delay) {

        /* Sets default values */
        if (!speed) speed = 500;
        if (!delay) delay = 6000;

        // If "delay" is less than 4 times the "speed", it will break the effect 
        // If that's the case, make "delay" exactly 4 times "speed"
        var quaSpd = (speed*4);
        if (quaSpd > (delay)) delay = quaSpd;

        // Create the variables needed
        var quote = $(this),
            firstQuo = $(this).filter(':first'),
            lastQuo = $(this).filter(':last'),
            wrapElem = '<div id="quote_wrap"></div>';

        // Wrap the quotes
        $(this).wrapAll(wrapElem);

        // Hide all the quotes, then show the first
        $(this).hide();
        $(firstQuo).show();

        // Set the hight of the wrapper
        $(this).parent().css({height: $(firstQuo).height()});       

        // Where the magic happens
        setInterval(function(){

            // Set required hight and element in variables for animation
            if($(lastQuo).is(':visible')) {
                var nextElem = $(firstQuo);
                var wrapHeight = $(nextElem).height();
            } else {
                var nextElem = $(quote).filter(':visible').next();
                var wrapHeight = $(nextElem).height();
            }

            // Fadeout the quote that is currently visible
            $(quote).filter(':visible').fadeOut(speed);

            // Set the wrapper to the hight of the next element, then fade that element in
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(quote).parent().animate({height: wrapHeight}, speed);
            }, speed);

            if($(lastQuo).is(':visible')) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(firstQuo).fadeIn(speed*2);
                }, speed*2);

            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(nextElem).fadeIn(speed);
                }, speed*2);
            }

        }, delay);

    };
})(jQuery);
```

I haved saved this code as a JS file within my website

And here is my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="../../style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.quovolver.js"></script>




<body>

         <div>
        I want my rotating quotes HERE


        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have been told to "Call the script in your document ready function with this line of code: `$(’element’).quovolver();`"

My question is, where and how do I store my quotes, and how do I call this Jquery plugin in the space i've noted in the html page?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found on the [documentation](http://sebnitu.github.com/Quovolver/):

### Javascript (jQuery)

```
// CASE : in an extern file
// When document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Call Quovolver on the '.quotes' object
  $('.quotes').quovolver();
});

// CASE : in HTML's head
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Call Quovolver on the '.quotes' object
      $('.quotes').quovolver();
    });
</script>
```

---

### HTML

```
<div class="quotes">
  <blockquote>
    <p>“That which can be asserted without evidence, can be dismissed without evidence.”</p>
    <p>— Christopher Hitchens (Quote 1)</p>
  </blockquote>

  <blockquote>
    <p>“Owners of dogs will have noticed that, if you provide them with food and water and shelter and affection, they will think you are god. Whereas owners of cats are compelled to realize that, if you provide them with food and water and shelter and affection, they draw the conclusion that they are gods.”</p>
    <p>— Christopher Hitchens (Quote 2)</p>
  </blockquote>

  <blockquote>
    <p>“Everybody does have a book in them, but in most cases that's where it should stay.”</p>
    <p>— Christopher Hitchens (Quote 3)</p>
  </blockquote>

  <blockquote>
    <p>“Beware the irrational, however seductive. Shun the 'transcendent' and all who invite you to subordinate or annihilate yourself. Distrust compassion; prefer dignity for yourself and others. Don't be afraid to be thought arrogant or selfish. Picture all experts as if they were mammals. Never be a spectator of unfairness or stupidity. Seek out argument and disputation for their own sake; the grave will supply plenty of time for silence. Suspect your own motives, and all excuses. Do not live for others any more than you would expect others to live for you.”</p>
    <p>— Christopher Hitchens (Quote 4)</p>
  </blockquote>

  <blockquote>
  <p>“Human decency is not derived from religion. It precedes it.”</p>
  <p>— Christopher Hitchens (Quote 5)</p>
  </blockquote>

  <blockquote>
    <p>“Many religions now come before us with ingratiating smirks and outspread hands, like an unctuous merchant in a bazaar. They offer consolation and solidarity and uplift, competing as they do in a marketplace. But we have a right to remember how barbarically they behaved when they were strong and were making an offer that people could not refuse.”</p>
    <p>— Christopher Hitchens (Quote 6)</p>
  </blockquote>
</div><!-- .quotes -->
```

Add the `.quotes` class to your `div`, fill it as this example, and call the jQuery code on the document's load.

Comment: Do I need to declare it as a script or something?

I sound really daft, but can you show me by example in my HTML example? Thanks

Comment: @user1345331 Updated answer: you fill the `.quote` div with your content following the pattern above.

Comment: Ok, almost got it.

Where do I place this snippet of code?

// When document is ready...
<code> $(document).ready(function() {
  // Call Quovolver on the '.quotes' object
  $('.quotes').quovolver();
}); </code>

In my html header, in the saved JS file, or in a new file?

Comment: @user1345331 In your head, wrapped within `<script>` tags, or in the JS file's `$(document).ready()`, or on a new file (still within the `$(document).ready()`) that you'll include in your `head`.

Comment: Ok perfect, 99% working...

Last question, when inserting the HTML parts, the quotes aren't seperating individually. i.e its fading all 5 in and out, rather than one at a time.. What is the solution here?

Thanks so much

Comment: @user1345331 I don't have any general solution, as I don't know this plugin. If you can provide me a link to your website or provide me some code, I'll check that with you. Meanwhile, if you think the original question have been answered, consider mark it as accepted, so we could move to the chat for further help without polluting the OP with debug information.

Comment: Here's the [link to the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26870/discussion-between-bigood-and-user1345331).